# Comparing Real GDP with different base years and currencies

Tags: gdp, currency, paneldata, purchasing-power-partity, base-year

I have a quarterly panel data of several countries. I have taken the data from Fred. Some countries' real gdp is in chained 2010 prices and some in other years (such as 2015 and 2018). How can I make it in the same basis?

And also these quarterly series are in their own national currencies. In order to have the common series, I have to change it to common currency. So I have taken data on PPP for GDP from the website of OECD. So my other question is that if my real gdp series are in chained 2010 prices, should I simply use 2010 exchange rate only for converting real gdp to another currency?

Comment: If you want consistent quarterly real terms GDP using PPP in a single currency, it might be better drawing from a single source, such as series VPVOBARSA from the OECD quarterly national accounts at  https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=QNA

Comment: Thanks. I found those series in fixed PPP. Can I use them as substitutes for Real GDP?

Comment: Look at the the percentage changes compared to a year earlier looking at pre-Covid times, and compare them to the percentage changes in the real GDP numbers you have from elsewhere.  If they are close enough then presumably yes; if they are very different then perhaps not.